# paperclip not saving attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've been using paperclip and everything was fine, till my server installed Passenger and  I cant make it work.
I have the most simple example of :image  like this:

```
has_attached_file :image , :url => "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension" , :default_url => "/:class/:attachment/missing.png", :styles=>{:lista=> "38x38#", :comunidad  => "50x50#", :destacado=>"100x100#",:perfil  => "150x150#"}
```

And the 4 fields on the database, and everything was working just fine..
Now in the log I have
[Paperclip] Saving Attachments...

But they are not being saved!
The directory permissions are ok.. but nothing happens.
Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using nginx? If so is your sendfile directive set to on?

Answer (score 3):

Have you placed multipart=>true in your form ? 
That solved my issue, which was similar.

```
form_for(@yourmodel, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f|
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you added:

```
attr_accessible :image
```

in your model? I forgot to add it to my model and the file would upload to the tmp dir, but would not store against the model when saving. So frustrating!